# Refresh OpenId Token after expiration in Cognito

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am using this [tutorial](https://java.awsblog.com/blog/author/Dhruv+Thukral) to create a developer authentication using AWS Cognito. The OpenId Token is set to expire after 10001 seconds. After the expiration of openId token, the new token has to be generated and sent to the user. What is the mechanism to generate a new OpenId token without requiring the user to login again?

Note: The posts in the tutorial are in descending order. So you will find the first post down, at the end of the tutorial.

Comment: Please post in the form of a question. As it is, I see no question in your post, just several statements, so I have no idea what you are asking. Are you asking how to refresh a token? Are you asking how to return a refreshed token to the client?

Comment: First, I second @MarkB here. What is the exact question? Although, I would like to point out that a simpler integration with Cognito can now be achieved through the [new Cognito User Pools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html) feature. It vends OpenId tokens and has APIs to refresh those tokens for users. Hopefully this fits your use case, you will not have to maintain your own back end.

Comment: @ChetanMehta, thanks. this is what I am looking to implement. I found the tutorial for implementing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-android-sdk.html) has the details on how to implement it.